# This page isn't working. mydomain.com took too long to respond. HTTP error 504, mysql grails

Tags: mysql, grails, groovy, grails-orm

I am working on this grails application that requires me to query and return information to the front page. The code works well on my local machine returning the correct result but returns an error in production, which could be because of the amount of data in the production database. Here is my code. I have a file called `MessageCount.groovy` with a class `MessageCount` and I have the following methods which I am calling from the class.

```
long getTotalMessageCountPerVertical(Verticals currentVertical) {
        long messagesCount = Messages.where {
            handle {
                msgDataSource {
                    verticals == currentVertical
                }
            }
        }.count()
        return messagesCount
    }


    long getTotalNumberOfTaggedMessages(Verticals currentVertical) {
        long taggedMessagesCount = Messages.where {
            handle {
                msgDataSource {
                    verticals == currentVertical
                }
            } && tagged == true && isSentToSentimentAPI == false
        }.count()
        return taggedMessagesCount
    }


    long getTotalNumberOfTaggedPhrases(Verticals currentVertical) {
        Users mlModel = Users.findByUsername("mlmodel@gmail.com")
        long taggedPhrase = Phrase.where {
            users != mlModel && messages {
                handle {
                    msgDataSource {
                        verticals == currentVertical
                    }
                }
            }
        }.count()
        return taggedPhrase
```

I have another file `CommentCount.groovy` which is calling the above queries from `CommentCount.groovy`

```
    def index(Integer max) {
        params.offset = (params.offset) ? params.offset : OFFSET
        params.max = Math.min(max ?: ROWS_PER_PAGE, 100)
        List<Verticals> verticals = Verticals.list(max: params.max, offset: params.offset)
        List taggedMessagesList = []

        long totalMessageCount
        long taggedMessagesCount
        long phraseCount

        verticals.each { currentVertical ->
            totalMessageCount = messageCountService.getTotalMessageCountPerVertical(currentVertical)
            taggedMessagesCount = messageCountService.getTotalNumberOfTaggedMessages(currentVertical)
            phraseCount = messageCountService.getTotalNumberOfTaggedPhrases(currentVertical)
            taggedMessagesList << [vertical: currentVertical, totalMsgCount: totalMessageCount, taggedMsgCount: taggedMessagesCount, phrCount: phraseCount]
        }

        render(view: 'index', model: [
                taggedMessagesList: taggedMessagesList,
                verticalCount     : verticals.totalCount
        ])
    }
```

Please is there a more efficient way to go about this? I will really appreciate your help.

[image]

Comment: add some log statements to see the how long each step is taking.

Comment: Ensure you have indexes on the fields you are constraining by. Check you query plan in the db to see what is taking the most time.

Comment: "Doing a .where{...}.count() is inefficient since you do not really need to bring back the full contents" - That shouldn't retrieve the full contents.  That should select a `select count(*)...` type query to the database.